# Play! Template syntax

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework 1.2.5. What is the difference between:

```
@{Application.render()}
```

and

```
@Application.render()
```

The first one is preferably used in the form action whereas the second one may be used for an anchor template. Both of them will be generating a URL, hence not able to understand which for the first one I need a `{}` surrounding braces.

Please let me know about this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{}` is a short cut to generate a relative url based on a reverse route (Controller.method -> URL)

`@@{}` gives you the absolute URL

`#{}` refer to tags. There just so happens to be an `#a` tag and you can do

```
#{a @Application.logout()}Disconnect#{/a}
```

because within the tag, you're actually passing the ActionDefinition when doing `@Application.logout()`, not the URL.

See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/tags

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need the curly braces when you use this in a template, for instance:
`<form action="@{Application.post}">`.

I just tried without the curly braces and that resulted in the exact string (@Application.render) and not an URL.

My code in the template:

```
@Application.index()<br />
@{Application.index()}<br />
```

Results in the following HTML in my browser:

```
@Application.index()<br />
/<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `#{a}` is also a built-in template then why we don't need the curly braces here?